# How can I search a complicated mapping?

Tags: python, elasticsearch

I'm using the python elasticsearch_dsl lib. I have quite complicated mappings and im having trouble searching. So far Im trying to return all with no luck, like this:

```
Search(using=es, index="test").query("match", query="*").execute()
```

So I thought this would return all docs in my DB but it didnt. I have noticed my schema is quite complicated. This is partly why i can't get it to retrive records.

```
    {
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "img": {
        "properties": {
          "ner": {
            "properties": {
              "img": {
                "type": "long"
              },
              "ner": {
                "properties": {
                  "description": {
                    "fields": {
                      "keyword": {
                        "ignore_above": 256,
                        "type": "keyword"
                      }
                    },
                    "type": "text"
                  },
                  "end": {
                    "type": "long"
                  },
                  "label": {
                    "type": "long"
                  },
                  "start": {
                    "type": "long"
                  },
                  "text": {
                    "fields": {
                      "keyword": {
                        "ignore_above": 256,
                        "type": "keyword"
                      }
                    },
                    "type": "text"
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          },
          "text": {
            "fields": {
              "keyword": {
                "ignore_above": 256,
                "type": "keyword"
              }
            },
            "type": "text"
          }
        }
      },
      "text": {
        "properties": {
          "ner": {
            "properties": {
              "description": {
                "fields": {
                  "keyword": {
                    "ignore_above": 256,
                    "type": "keyword"
                  }
                },
                "type": "text"
              },
              "end": {
                "type": "long"
              },
              "label": {
                "type": "long"
              },
              "start": {
                "type": "long"
              },
              "text": {
                "fields": {
                  "keyword": {
                    "ignore_above": 256,
                    "type": "keyword"
                  }
                },
                "type": "text"
              }
            }
          },
          "text": {
            "fields": {
              "keyword": {
                "ignore_above": 256,
                "type": "keyword"
              }
            },
            "type": "text"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "settings": {
    "index": {
      "creation_date": "1601510772055",
      "number_of_replicas": "1",
      "number_of_shards": "1",
      "provided_name": "test",
      "uuid": "wV6MC8JoRkGA_Vw8IsP7yw",
      "version": {
        "created": "7090299"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

What would be the correct way for me to search the text->ner->text? Also can you see any problems with the mappings that could be causing this problem if it isn't a searching problem but a mapping one.

Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by `text->ner->text?`, could you please explain this **correct way for me to search the text->ner->text?**

Comment: I am afraid its very difficult to provide the answer with the information you provided, please provide your use-case, sample docs and expected search results